# What is this: $('<div />')

Tags: jquery

In a tutorial I came across this jQuery:

```
var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
```

I havent seen the `'<div />'` before. Doesnt look like a CSS selector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction creates new jQuery object which contains one `div` element. It can be slightly shorter though: `$("<div>")`

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Didnt know you could do this.

Answer (score 5):

I slightly differs if you say, `selector`.

That is [Jquery Html attribute](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (`i.e., it starts with <tag ... >`). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.

Ex

```
$( "<p id='test'>My <em>new</em> text</p>" ).appendTo( "body" );
```

Answer (score 4):

This simply isn't a selector at all but some HTML

```
var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
```

is equivalent to

```
var encodedName = $('<div></div>').text(name).html();
```

or

```
var encodedName = $('<div>').text(name).html(); // HTML fragments are automatically closed
```

It builds a jQuery element from some HTML, gives it some text, and then gets the innerHTML.

The purpose of this code is obviously to encode a string as HTML. For example

```
console.log($('<div>').text("3 < 4").html());
```

logs

```
"3 &lt; 4"
```

Answer (score 2):

`<div />` is an empty div element. With `$('<div />')` you create an empty div element as jquery object (not yet in the DOM / on the page) which you can then manipulate and later insert into your page if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The output of a `$(...)` jQuery selector is always a reference to a Document element (or a zero length collection). In order for that to be true. It will construct DOM elements in memory to satisfy this requirement.

So `$('<div>')` returns a reference to jQuery where a `DIV` element has been selected, but is not in the DOM. jQuery has created it in memory only.

You can then append this to the current document, like so;

```
$('<div>').appendTo('body');
```

You can also perform selection on the returned object, like so;

```
$('<div><span class="stuff"></span></div>').find('.stuff').html("<span>something else</span>");
```